# htaccess redirect from path/path to path?path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Can a .htaccess guru help me with how to do this:

Urls like this

> example.com/quest/name/anything

Should redirect with 301 to

> example.com/quest/name?date=anything

But if third arg is 'edit' than it stays still

> example.com/quest/name/edit - untouched

And one more thing – "name" is unique and changes, so the path is:

> example.com/quest/%/anything -> example.com/quest/%?date=anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(quest/[^/]+)/((?!(?:edit|exclude1|exclude2))[^/]+)/?$ http%{ENV:protossl}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I modified a bit rule, because it didn't want to work.
Here is working:
`RewriteRule ^(quest/[^/]+)/((?!edit)[^/]+)/?$ http%{ENV:protossl}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?date=$2 [L,NC,QSA,R=301]`

Comment: Can you also help me and show how to add more "exceptions" like "edit"?

Comment: check updated answer for excluding more words as `edit`, `exclude1`, `exclude2` etc.

Comment: Thank you very much one more time!